# Trying to use ID instead of XPATH

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This code as of now works fine. But when I use this function to iterate over a spreadsheet after it will not click the "More Details". It will only work using one parcel number. I assume its because I'm using the XPATH instead of ID, not sure. Can anyone help me find the correct element for this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

def gis_website():
    """Navigate to the GIS website, search for a parcel, and click the search button."""
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #options.add_argument('--headless')
        #options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get("https://isv.kcsgis.com/al.etowah_revenue/")
        time.sleep(10)  # Increase wait time to 10 seconds

        button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/button')
        button.click()

        # If the element appears, the accept button has been clicked successfully
        print("Accept button clicked successfully!")

        # Wait for the "Go to Map" button to appear and then click it
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        go_to_map = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/aside/button')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", go_to_map)
        print("Go to map button clicked successfully!")

        # Wait for the overlay to disappear or become invisible
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        overlay = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "dijitDialogUnderlay")))
        
        # click the parcel number box
        input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[@class='dj_webkit dj_chrome dj_contentbox blueTheme has-webkit has-no-quirks']/body[@class='dbootstrap']/div[@id='borderContainerOuter']/div[@id='sidebarLeft']/div[@id='search_parent']/div[@class='dijitTitlePaneContentOuter']/div[@class='dijitReset']/div[@id='search_parent_pane']/div[@id='search_widget']/div[@id='dijit_layout_TabContainer_0']/div[@class='dijitTabPaneWrapper dijitTabContainerTop-container dijitAlignCenter']/div[@class='dijitTabContainerTopChildWrapper dijitVisible']/div[@id='dijit_layout_ContentPane_0']/div[@id='divAttributeQueryText']/div[@id='widget_dijit_form_TextBox_2']/div[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer']/input")
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(input_box).click().perform()

        # Send keys to the input box element
        input_box.send_keys("1009314000067000")
        time.sleep(5)
        
        # locate the search button and click it
        #search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='dijit_form_Button_1_label']")
        search_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='dijit_form_Button_1_label']")))
        search_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        print("Parcel number typed in and search button clicked successfully!")
    
        more_details = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tr/td[8]')
        more_details.click()
        
        
        print("More detials clicked succesfully")
        
        # Wait for the new tab to open
        wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

        # Get the handles of all open windows/tabs
        window_handles = driver.window_handles

        # Switch to the newly opened tab (the last one in the list)
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[-1])

        # Get the URL of the current window
        new_window_url = driver.current_url

        # Print the URL
        print(new_window_url)
       
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        driver.quit()

gis_website()
```

This is the only part of the code I need the correct element for:

```
more_details = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tr/td[8]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
more_details = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="More Details"]')
more_details.click()
```

Or try using `ExplicitWaits` like below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
more_details = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="More Details"]')))
more_details.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

For only relying on the ID i suggest to use:

```
//*/*[@Id='Id_of_btn']
```

resulting in:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*/*[@Id='Id_of_btn']').click()
```

With the '*' syntax it does not matter which element you are trying to find and focus on ID´s only.

For further information see:

[W3-Schools.xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)